# Clustering vs Forking in NodeJS HTTP Server

Tags: node.js, http, fork, cluster-computing, httpserver

Is forking more efficient* as compared to clustering in NodeJS HTTP Server?
More specifically I'm talking about using `http` module of NodeJS and `child_process.fork` and `cluster` module.

*The term efficient constitutes of memory usage and average throughput.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34682035/cluster-and-fork-mode-difference-in-pm2

Comment: The above talks about `pm2` which is a advanced process manager.

Comment: The answer and most of the arguments still apply because they're talking about the core concepts of clusters and fork. Can you see if they actually help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From NodeJS [official docs](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works)

> The worker processes are spawned using the child_process.fork()
>   method, so that they can communicate with the parent via IPC and pass
>   server handles back and forth.

The cluster module supports methods for distributing incoming connections, while forking requires you to handle the connections on your own.