# how to solve pm2 error in cluster-mode with ts-node

Tags: typescript, express, pm2, ts-node

I'm trying to use pm2 with ts-node for deployment.

When I use `cluster-mode`, pm2 instance error occurs that Cannot find module...

> Error: Cannot find module '{path}/start'
>
> at main ({path}/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:178:20)
>
> at Object. ({path}/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:404:5)

Here is my ecosystem.config.js and `"production": "pm2-runtime start ecosystem.config.js --env production"` this is my package script.

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
   {
            script: "ts-node",
            args: "./server.ts",
            instances: "max",
            exec_mode: 'cluster_mode',
            node_args: '-r esm'
            env_production: {...}
   }
  ]
}
```

When I use `fork-mode` not `cluster-mode`, The app works well.
I don't know how to solve this problem.
please tell me any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, using any interpreter other than JS requires fork mode thus prohibits direct execution oy typescript. You need to compile /server.ts to /server.js to enable cluster mode.

[https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/tutorials/using-transpilers-with-pm2#execution-interpreter](http://Using%20transpilers%20with%20PM2)

> The easiest way to use transpilers with PM2 is to override the
>   execution interpreter (exec_interpreter). Note that if this is
>   changed, your code will only work in fork_mode.

[Cluster and Fork mode difference in PM2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34682035/cluster-and-fork-mode-difference-in-pm2)